# Fuzzy graph matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, fuzzy, subgraph

I have a fuzzy graph `G=(V, E)` where `V` is the set of vertices and `E` is the set of edges. Every vertex is a fuzzy vertex, that means, it has a property with a membership function associated to it (stored in the vertex somehow). Every edge is a fuzzy edge, that means, it has a property with a membership function associated to it (stored in the edge somehow). By doing this, `G` is a fuzzy graph in terms of edges and vertices.

Given `G` and `G2`, another fuzzy graph with different (or equal) number of edges and/or vertices, I need to compare both graphs in a fuzzy way. I want to check if `G2` is a subgraph or `G` (or vice versa). Is there any algorithm to address this?

Comment: I think I don't get you... @Yonlif

Comment: The function is stored in the vertex/edge somehow. So, when comparing two nodes/edges, you can call it to check the value of the node/edge for comparing it. @Yonlif

Comment: Oh I get it now! Do you need to address the function computation time?

Comment: Well, the algorithm should be as fast as possible, but this is not the main goal. Regarding the membership function, it should be `O(1)`, so don't worry about it. @Yonlif

Comment: So each vertex has a function which can be passed another vertex and returns a boolean indicating whether the second vertex is a member of the first?

Comment: What is a "membership function?"  What is the signature of these functions and what do they compute?  Subgraph isomorphism is trivially O(n) if vertices and edges are labeled.

Comment: @Richard each vertex and each edge has a membership function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membership_function_(mathematics)) associated to the fuzzy set that it represents. This function will return a value (normally between 0 and 1) that will be used to compare nodes/edges. Two nodes will be similar if they have a similar value for their membership functions. The comparison should be fuzzy.

Comment: @Gene take a look at my previous comment please.

Comment: @Néstor What do you mean by «comparing in a fuzzy way»? As far as I understand you need to know if there is a perfect match between G and G2. What if e.g. the match is 1-near perfect? or 2-near, etc.?

Comment: @hidefromkgb You can have concrete/crisp information or fuzzy information. I need to compare both graphs in a fuzzy way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic In fact, I don't need a perfect match, I need to know how similar are both graphs or how much is one graph a subgraph of the other one.

Comment: @Néstor I understand what fuzzy logic is. What I don\`t is the term «comparing in a fuzzy way». How similar «in a fuzzy way» are e.g. a triangle-shaped graph and a square-shaped graph?

Comment: @hidefromkgb The fuzziness is in the nodes and edges, not in the graph. Imagine two trivial graphs, G1 and G2 with one node each one. Both nodes represent a fuzzy color. The node in G1 has a membership degree to the red color of 0.7. The node in G2 has a membership degree to the red color of 0.7. G2 is a subgraph of G1 with a 1.0 of matching. Same situation but now the node in G2 has a membership degree to the red color of 0.5. G2 is a subgraph of G1 with a X degree of matching where 0.0 < X < 1.0.

Comment: @Néstor So what is the similarity metric by which X gets computed? Is it e.g. exp(–abs(e₁ – e₂)) or, say, 2cot⁻¹(abs(e₁ – e₂))/π, or even a Dirac delta? And then, how does that metric scale beyond a single graph node? These two things are crucial to devise an algorithm, for without them we won\`t be able to answer whether it`s better to e.g. cover all nodes but get a <1.0 metric on any of them, or to cover less nodes but maintain a strict 1.0, all that stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194995/discussion-between-nestor-and-hidefromkgb).

Comment: I have created a chat based on stackoverflow's suggestion, take a look at my previous comment @hidefromkgb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to compare two graphs you should solve the [Subgraph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem), it could be polynomial or not.

But you have not graphs, you have fuzzy graphs. I don't know if explicit algorithm exists but I would try two approaches:

1. If you can define membership as a probability, you can first find "the maximum similarity" assuming usual graphs (`P{is member}=1`) and then, try to find some relation using [Bayesian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) (if acyclic) or in a more general way using [Markov random fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field).
2. You can define a metric between fuzzy graphs using [Monte Carlo methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm). As an **example** simply walk the two graphs and stop when one step produce some difference. The number of steps is a metric. Run `n` times and get the `max`, `avg`, ... The final algorithm depends strongly if your membership function have state, you know "the maximum similarity" and so...

The former approach should be fast and reliable but you have nothing if you can't find the adequate equations. The latter approach, looks more feasible but much less efficient.

Anyway, the usability of the defined metric is subjetive (if you don't explain the requirements, any metric could be valid).

Answer (score 1):

These might be helpful:
[A fuzzy graph matching approach in intelligence analysis and maintenance of continuous situational awareness](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1566253513000572)

[An approach for approximate subgraph matching in fuzzy RDF graph](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165011419301538)